# PostgreSQL equivalent of SQL Server's IDENTITY(1, 2)

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

Having this sample table:

```
create table testingCase (
id integer not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
constraint pk_testingCase primary key (id),
description varchar(60)
);
```

I want the id to be **AUTO INCREMENTED** by 2 (for example), in `SQL Server` that'd be `IDENTITY (1, 2)`.

How can this be achieved utilizing PostgreSQL?

Comment: You can do this by declaring a sequence manually.  I would question why you would want to do such a thing.  It sounds suspiciously like you want to tables to have the same "id", one with evens and odds.  There may be better solutions -- such as inheritance -- to do what you want.

Comment: Why do you want a step of 2? If you want multiple tables to share the same ID numbers you can use a single sequence both in SQL Server and PostgreSQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm merely asking out of curiosity, considering I'm new to Postgres and because I found MSSQL's AUTO INCREMENT useful in the past.

Comment: @Outman SQL Server's also has sequences. Increments other than 1 though aren't very common. How did you use such increments in SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think I've *ever* had an `IDENTITY` with an increment that wasn't 1, in any database. The reason is simply that due to the implementation, `IDENTITY` cannot guarantee consecutive or "gapless" values, no matter the increment used (and `RESEED` can reseed to anything), which makes it a design mistake to rely on the increment to give you particular values only, or at least a maintenance headache. `IDENTITY`: useful. Creative values for the increment: not half as useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sequence options like in [CREATE SEQUENCE.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

```
create table testing_case (
    id integer not null generated always as identity (increment by 2),
    constraint pk_testing_case primary key (id),
    description varchar(60)
);

insert into testing_case (description) 
values ('a'), ('b'), ('c')
returning *

 id | description 
----+-------------
  1 | a
  3 | b
  5 | c
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the concern in the comments above but I only wanted to know this answer, not its use case.